# How to fix issue of incompatibility between angular project and a vega (charts library)?

Tags: angular, typescript, vega-lite

I'm currently working on a angular 7 project, and i want to add vega library for charts.
the issue i think is the fact that vega requires a higher version of typescript (3.4.4) and inside my project its only (3.2.2).

So when i try to run the project, i'm having an error like this :

**ERROR in node_modules/vega-lite/build/src/util.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"P:/projects/ui/project/node_modules/@types/clone"' has no exported member 'default'.
node_modules/vega-lite/build/src/util.d.ts(2,8): error TS1192: Module '"P:/projects/ui/project/node_modules/@types/fast-json-stable-stringify/index"' has no default export.**

so could be please give me an idea , how to solve this kind of issues , if you have lower version of typescript in your application and a higher one in another library.

thank you

Comment: Well if they are not compatible, you have to either downgrade Vega or upgrade typescript. I would recommend upgrading TS to be up to date with the latest version. You will run into a lot of compatibility issues in the future if you insist on remaining on older versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular 7 currently uses TypeScript 3.2.2 so your Angular TypeScript version is as expected.

You could manually try changing the version of TypeScript in `package.json` then do an `npm install` and see what happens. If it errors out then it's going to be a problem for you.

Another suggestion is you could switch to the release candidate for Angular 8.

Run this ...

```
npm view @angular/cli versions --json
```

Currently it shows there is a version 8 release candidate available called 8.0.0-rc.2

So you could do

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@8.0.0-rc.2
```

and then create a new project and see if Angular 8 is using a newer version of TypeScript. If so you could copy your code to the new Angular 8 project or you could wait for the release of Angular 8 which is expected very soon (May 2019) and then just use

```
ng update
```

to upgrade to 8.

Alternatively, downgrade vega or look for a different library.